# Use NGINX for AD Authentication of both API users and Web Users

Tags: nginx, active-directory, authentication

We are currently using an NGINX server as a reverse proxy for a variety of services and applications. It is handling and proxying traffic to a web application we have created, an API Proxy server, as well as a separate programmatic API. Below is a sample diagram showing the resources behind the proxy.

```
​   foobar.com
    |-foobar.com/api
    |-foobar.com/webapp
    |-foobar.com/proxy
```

We have a corporate AD system with Single-Sign On capabilities. I am trying to integrate this with the NGINX reverse proxy to authenticate users when the access one or more of these services behind NGINX.

I have seen posts like https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-authenticate-users/ describe how to have NGINX use AD Authentication of users by having users fill out a login form, but this will not work for our use case. This is because some of these users will be interacting with the API service and the proxy service via HTTP CRUD operations and/or curl commands.  In addtion, these API and proxy users may belong to other applications and not human beings. In that sense, they are fully programmatic interactions.

How can I configure NGINX to support both Human and Programmatic AD Authentication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no thing like an AD Authentication. What you are looking for is [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) authentication via [GSSAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Security_Services_Application_Program_Interface). To get such an authentication for browser [SPNEGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPNEGO) is used. I just enumerate all these terms to give you a better starting point for further research.

The link you provided has nothing to do with SSO. It only describes a method to authenticate using the ADs LDAP interface.

For the type of authentication you want to implement you have to use the ADs Kerberos interface.

nginx does not support Kerberos out of the box. As far as I know 
[spnego-http-auth-nginx-module](https://github.com/stnoonan/spnego-http-auth-nginx-module) is the least experimental way to implement Kerberos authentication in nginx.

Somewhat beyond the scope of your question: Apache has a very mature Kerberos module mod_auth_kerb and the somewhat newer mod_auth_gssapi.

This is not meant as a recommandation. My personal experience is mostly limited to using Kerberos in Java applications behind a Apache/mod_proxy_ajp/Tomcat facade.